# How to use php in a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php

```
<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- Amount $5.50 -->
        cryptobox_show(1514, 'bitcoin', '1514AAf8QICBitcoin77BTCPUB7XBxPbmc4uK79CCWHEB5DAmY', 0, 5.5, '60 MINUTE', 'en', 'box1913', 'user4', 'MANUAL', 'product1', '', '', 'f2cea21af212b8a60a1620bc46ea8f79', 530, 230);
    </script>
```

how do i replace the cryptobox_show with php code and a javascript viarable

```
function cryptobox_show(boxID, coinName, public_key, amount, amountUSD, period, language, iframeID, userID, userFormat, orderID, cookieName, webdev_key, hash, width, height)
```

for example;

```
cryptobox_show($id, 'bitcoin', '$key', 0, 5.5, '60 MINUTE', 'en', 'box1913', '$user', 'MANUAL', 'product1', '', '', 'javascript viarable', 530, 230);
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more context here.

Comment: I didn't think you can, PHP and JavaScript is two different languages, you maybe need to learn more about PHP restful API  and AJAX maybe it will help you

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a client-side language and PHP is a server-side language, so the two cannot be mixed and used together without using AJAX and getting the results from the call. However, it looks like you're only wanting to use PHP variables inside of your JavaScript function, which can be done easily, only if they are both inside of a PHP file. All you have to do is get the value of the variables in PHP, and echo the value of the variables to JavaScript variables. This will only work for scalar data. If you're wanting to go beyond simply accessing PHP variables in JavaScript, unfortunately this cannot be done.

```
<?php
    $id = id;
    $key = key;
    $user = user;
?>

<script>
    const id = '<?php echo $id;?>';
    const key = '<?php echo $key;?>';
    const user = '<?php echo $user;?>';
    cryptobox_show(id, 'bitcoin', key, 0, 5.5, '60 MINUTE', 'en', 'box1913', user, 'MANUAL', 'product1', '', '', 'javascript viarable', 530, 230);
</script>
```

Comment: var hash = calcMD4("44324|Speedcoin|44324AAwl7hASpeedcoin77SPDPUBd9FJQrSeVkHQ15pYutYBf|44324AAwl7hASpeedcoin77SPDPRVPVNAq3tstzXnjFWDABqM4||0|0.3|1 DAY|en|livedemo|user|MANUAL|box158211430|0|044324|Speedcoin|44324AAwl7hASpeedcoin77SPDPUBd9FJQrSeVkHQ15pYutYBf|44324AAwl7hASpeedcoin77SPDPRVPVNAq3tstzXnjFWDABqM4||0|0.3|1 DAY|en|livedemo|102994747__25be230ad0|MANUAL|box158211430|0|0"); how to call on this using 'const'

Comment: `const` is just ES6+ syntax for `var`, you can stick with `var`

Comment: Now getting it. can i use the 'const' values in a variable.. for example; `var hash = id;` that is the `const id` or using the above `var hash = calcMD4("id|speedcoin....|user)`